# ETCS set theory: Are empty sets isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Just a quick question about ETCS: Are any two empty sets isomorphic? Here, a set $X$ is empty if there exists no $x \in X$, i.e. no functions $x: 1 \to X$.

The reason I'm asking is that I need this to show that empty sets are initial sets.

Thank you!

Comment: Any two initial objects are isomorphic, in a unique way. So it suffices to show that empty sets are initial.

Comment: is there more than one empty set?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes, but the problem lies in showing that empty sets are initial. If $X$ is empty and $Y$ is any set, then how does one cook up a function $X \to Y$ when $Y$ is empty?

Comment: @magma: In ZFC there is only one empty set by extensionality, but in ETCS I don't think there's any problem in having several empty sets.

Comment: @Svinepels It is an _axiom_ that there is an initial object. Are you asking whether a set that has no elements is initial?

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, precisely. I have shown that any initial set must necessarily be empty. However, the converse seems a little trickier.

Comment: @Svinepels that was the reason of my question. I am not very familiar with ETCS, but i would be very surprised to find out that it allows more than one empty set, if it has any pretense of mimicking the category of sets. So try to prove that there is exactly one empty set.

Comment: @magma That is not true. ETCS is formulated in an equivalence-invariant way, so it is perfectly possible to have more than one empty set.

Comment: @ZhenLin so the category (or categories) describef by ETCS is equivalent to SET, but not necessarily isomorphic? Having more than one empty set has no weird consequences?

Comment: That statement presupposes a notion of $\mathbf{Set}$, which is precisely what ETCS is axiomatising!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of the theory of sets as a well-pointed topos, if an object is empty it will be initial. Take $i:0\to A$ and $id_A:A\to A$. Assuming $A$ non-initial, $0$ will not be isomorphic with $A$, so $\chi_i:A\to\Omega\neq\chi_{id_A}:A\to\Omega$. By well-pointedness, there must be a point $x:1\to A$ that distingushes them. Hence from $\neg(A\cong 0)$ we have derived that $A$ must have a point.

EDIT:
Forgot an important extra piece of information: Initial objects must be empty in a Cartesian closed category, on pain of triviality. So all non-initial objects are non-empty, and all initial objects (by assumption in most topoi) are empty.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be an externally two-valued elementary topos with the axiom of finite choice, i.e. there are only two subobjects of $1$ in $\mathcal{S}$ (up to isomorphism) and any epimorphism with codomain $1$ is a split epimorphism. If $X$ is an object in $\mathcal{S}$ such that there do not exist any morphism $1 \to X$, then $X$ is an initial object in $\mathcal{S}$. Indeed, let $U \rightarrowtail 1$ be the image of the unique morphism $X \to 1$. If $U$ is a terminal object then the unique morphism $X \to 1$ is an epimorphism, in which case the axiom of finite choice implies it has a section, i.e. there exists a morphism $1 \to X$. Thus $U$ is not a terminal object – so it must be an initial object, by two-valuedness. But initial objects in cartesian closed categories are strict, so $X \to U$ must be an isomorphism, and so $X$ must itself be an initial object.

Note that $\mathcal{S}$ need not be well-pointed for the above proof to work: for example, $\mathcal{S}$ could be the topos of simplicial sets. Conversely, any non-degenerate elementary topos with the property that "empty objects are initial" must be externally two-valued and have the axiom of finite choice.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting that this holds without well-pointedness. As we see from Malice Vidrine's proof, assuming well-pointedness gives a considerably shorter proof.